# Nginx 502 bad gateway error in React and Nodejs with https

Tags: reactjs, node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I deployed react and node.js on digital ocean server.
I used nginx and pm2 for deploying react and nodejs and connected react and node.js to a domain.
Just it seems like https://my_domain.com (this is react) and https://my_domain.com/api(this is Node.js).
I configured proxy on nginx conf and site available.

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffers 24 4k;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /overview {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/overview;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffers 24 4k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 32k;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
 
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/waymol.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/waymol.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}server {
  if ($host = example.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

node.js api configured api/message and api/category.
React call node.js https://example.com/api/message or https://example.com/api/category.
I can get all data with get request but can't send post request.
How can I fix this error?